# Getting new Date with FMT and SpringMVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a problem with FMT and SpringMVC:

I have an object which contains a date field, so i use fmt to show it in my jsp page like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${form.dtBegin}" type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

The problem is that when i submit my page, this field "form.dtBegin" get a new Date and in my case this field should not change!!

So have you any idea for this problem?

Thanx all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try binding date in your controller.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), true));
}
```